# why is 'this' keyword returning address of class B?

Tags: java

When I call the super class method ma() it is printing the address of B.My question is in this program what is the function of this keyword. Why using this keyword inside print statement not giving syntax error rather it gives error for the super keyword.why it will print reference of B only why not A class.

```
  class A
    {
       public void ma()
       {
           System.out.print(this); //printing address of B why?
       }
    }
    class B extends A 
    {
      public void mb()
      {
         super.ma();  //calling super class method
      }
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
       A re=new B(); //creating object for class B
        re.mb();   //calling method mb() of class B
      }
    }
```

Comment: ...because you're creating a `B`, and therefore `this` is a `B`?

Comment: what makes this to print only the address of B ? How this internally works in this program?

Comment: There is no address here. There is the result of calling `Object.toString()`. This is not an address.

Comment: It's not printing address. It's printing the hash code, because you haven't overridden `toString`. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--

Comment: "Why using this keyword inside print statement not giving syntax error rather it gives error for the super keyword." What syntax error did you expect it to give? "Rather it gives error for the super keyword." Where? It's not clear what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

[`this`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) is a reference to the **current object** — the object whose method or constructor is being called

`ma()` method of class `A` is indirectly invoked using instance of class `B`.

```
    A re=new B(); //creating object for class B
    re.mb();
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` always refer to the object on which the method is called. **Always**.

Look closely at your code, have you *ever* created a new instance of `A`? No. Then no identifier can refer to an `A` object, so logically your code can never output the address of an `A` object.

I think you misunderstood the meaning of `super`. It just means "to call the super class implementation of this method", not "call this method by creating an instance of the super class". Therefore, `super` will only make a difference if your derived class has a different implementation of the method. Here, it doesn't.

Even though you are calling the super implementation, the object on which you call this method does not change. It is still `this`.

Comment: @AjithKM if you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!